# Overide methods when instantiated using findviewbyid

Tags: android

I had a question on overriding methods.
When i instantiate a view i'm having 2 options.

1.Instantiate view programatically.

```
View view = new View( .... ){
      onDraw(){

         .......
      }

 };
```

2.Instantiate view from layout.

```
View view = findViewbyid(...){

        onDraw(){
           .......
        }
};
```

My question is, is there any possibility to override methods as shown in 2nd option.?

Thanks & Regards,

Sha.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the second option is not possible. However, you may create your custom class which `extends View` and override whatever you want inside.

Answer (score 2):

No, You can't do it with the second option. 
when you use `findViewById` you are already instantiating the native Android View class, and it calls the constructor:
`public View (Context context, AttributeSet attrs)`.
You must create your custom View and override there the implementation of 
`onDraw(Canvas canvas)` to adapt to your needs.

Comment: No, using `findViewById()` you're not instantiating anything, and certainly not calling any constructor. You're just getting the reference to the already instantiated `View` object.

Comment: Try to make a Custom View and add it to your XML, then `findViewById(R.id.customView)` will call the Default Constructor!